# Area defined by cylindrical coordinate equations

Tags: geometry

I'm supposed to find the area of a space defined by these equations.

1. r=3
2. 0$ \le $$ \theta $$ \le $$ \textstyle\frac{ \pi }{2} $
3. 0$ \le $z$ \le $2

I tried applying A = $ \int^b_a 0.5r^2\,d\theta $, but I didn't get anywhere. Also I don't know whether or not this is the right formula to use here.

Comment: Why did you try applying _that_ formula? There are zillions formulae known in mathematics. What made you belive that the randomly picked one may give you a reasonable answer if you don't even know if it is 'right to use here'?

Answer (score 1):

$r=3$ defines a cylinder, inequalities' pair for $z$ defines a length of the cylinder segment and inequality for $\theta$ defines a quater of that segment. So the area element is $r\,d\theta\cdot dz$ while the double integrating area is given by 2. and 3.